# How can I fix this regex to match an object in Json and replace it as a list of Object

Tags: python, json, regex, string

I have tried the following but i am failing to match the object in Json

```
:\s*(\{[^\"]*\})
```

I want to know the way to replace the object type in Json as list of object.

Here is the sample of Json:

```
{
  "resourceType": "ChargeItem",
  "id": "example",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
    "session": "Done"
  },
  "identifier": [
    {
      "system": "http://myHospital.org/ChargeItems",
      "value": "654321"
    }
  ],
  "definitionUri": [
    "http://www.kbv.de/tools/ebm/html/01520_2904360860826220813632.html"
  ],
  "status": "billable",
  "code": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "code": "01510",
        "display": "Zusatzpauschale für Beobachtung nach diagnostischer Koronarangiografie"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need i want to convert to this form:

```
{
  "resourceType": "ChargeItem",
  "id": "example",
  "text": [{
    "status": "generated",
    "session": "Done"
  }],
  "identifier": [
    {
      "system": "http://myHospital.org/ChargeItems",
      "value": "654321"
    }
  ],
  "definitionUri": [
    "http://www.kbv.de/tools/ebm/html/01520_2904360860826220813632.html"
  ],
  "status": "billable",
  "code": [{
    "coding": [
      {
        "code": "01510",
        "display": "Zusatzpauschale für Beobachtung nach diagnostischer Koronarangiografie"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to manipulate it as an object instead of trying to change it's structure as a string?

Comment: You don't want to use regex to modify a JSON string. This will easilly end up with incorrect format. You'd rather deserialize it, then process, then serialize it again

Comment: Regex is great for simple operations but somethings are just easier to do by manipulating the object, especially in this case.  Look into how to convert json to a dict and how manipulate a `dict` in python. This is really easy.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a few simple transformations:

First, change

```
"text": {
```

to

```
"text": [{
```

Second, change

```
},
"identifier": [
```

to

```
}],
"identifier": [
```

Third, change

```
 "code": {
```

to

```
 "code": [{
```

And finally, change

```
  }
}
<EOF>
```

to

```
  }]
}
<EOF>
```

However, it might not be as straightforward as it appears, i.e. what if the `identifer` section isn't always present, or doesn't immediately follow the `text` section?

Regular expressions are a poor choice for doing this work.  It would be much better to read the json file into a native Python data structure, apply your desired changes, then save the json back to the file.

Comment: i want to convert something like 
"key": {
"something": "something1"
} 
to
"key": [{
"something": "something1"
}]
regardless of their names

Comment: The main difficulty is in adding the ending `]`, because it doesn't appear on the same line as the key, and you can't globally add a `]` after every `}`.

Comment: so it just need to match : { } 
and replace with : [{ }]

Comment: No.  For example, the `identifier` section is _already_ a list; presumably you don't want to convert it to list-of-list.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a multiline regexp search

```
>>> import re

>>> blocks = re.compile(r'(?ms)(.*)("text": )([{][^{}]+[}])(,.*"status": "billable"[^"]+)("code": )([{][^"]+"coding":[^]]+\]\s+\})')
>>> m = blocks.search(s)
>>> result = ""
>>> for i in range(1,len(m.groups()) + 1):
...   if i not in (3,6):
...     result += m.group(i)
...   else:
...     result += "[" + m.group(i) + "]"
... 
>>> result += "\n}"
```